# Can't load json object in python, getting AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'loads'

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm on python3 trying to read/load a json object which looks like:

```
{"a":[], "b":[], "c":[]}
```

I get the same error after trying many different ways to load it.

```
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'load'
```

I've tried:

```
with open('data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

and also

```
with open('data.json') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
```

and also

```
with open('data.json') as f:
    data = json.loads())
```

I'm pretty stuck, and I just want to load a json file, append to it, and then save it again.

Comment: Have you assigned to `json` variable something before?

Comment: Are you reading a file?

Comment: Is this a file or a dict?

Comment: File which holds a dict

Comment: [Please don't add "solved" to your title or question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/248627). Instead, [mark an answer correct by clicking on the checkmark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/248627). You can also [add your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept it if none of the ones you received solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’d guess you have something like the following in your code:

`json = requests.get(url)`

You could check by doing this just before your lines:

`import json`

Answer (score 0):

(Too low reputation to comment, sorry)

Sounds like you're trying to read a web response; have you used the variable name json elsewhere in the program?